# Tabulator: React formater: need 'dispose' handler for a correct implementation

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

[react-tabulator](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator) is a library providing an integration of Tabulator in React. Their solution to render a React component within a Tabulator formater uses [this function](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/blob/9d0d09876fe79243cbcd2c9726e11acfd79f6158/src/Utils.tsx#L21). However, I don't think this is 100% correct, because based on the [React doc on integrating React w/ plain JS](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#embedding-react-in-a-backbone-view), `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode()` needs to be called on dispose in order to to some cleanup. I also communicated this to the author within a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/issues/135#issuecomment-620204999), and maybe he'll provide additional info.

My question: is there a hook/handler/way to receive notifications when a cell is being disposed? 1) This will allow me to call the mentioned method, so that React can do some cleanup. 2) This opens also the path towards an alternative approach, leveraging React portals.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an implementation using portals in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cristian-spiescu/30b0781745066db3e27a10198f788228). It's a Storybook pages. I'm using `semantic-ui-react` in my project, so a copy/paste of the file may need adapting.

I don't know if it's OK to have thousands of portals. I.e. one per cell. Also, I didn't see any action do "dispose" a portal. I hope that disposing the DOM element where the portal was rendered suffices. Otherwise => memory leaks possible I think.